# Scala: parameterless classes vs traits

Tags: scala, traits

Scala distinguishes between parameterless classes, and traits. Why? 
Is there a reason why I should not declare all parameterless classes into traits?

Comment: That's right. Can you make this an answer, so I can mark this question as done?

Comment: When people agree that it is a duplicate, it will just be closed and link to the previous question. That's fine usually

Answer (score 0):

For example, a trait cannot be instantiated